# Boost socket send_to() problems

Tags: c++11, boost-asio

We have a project that uses a wrapper for Boost socket. I'm trying to add a wrapper for the sent_to() command, but can't get it to compile. We're using C++11.

In the header file, this:

```
template<typename ConstBufferSequence>
std::size_t send_to(
        const ConstBufferSequence & buffers,
        const endpoint_type & destination,      // error
        socket_base::message_flags flags,       // error
        boost::system::error_code & ec);
```

generates two errors. They are:

- "Type 'endpoint_type' could not be resolved", and
- "Type 'socket_base::message_flags' could not be resolved

I've included the requisite header file, and even a more direct one:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp>
```

Neither resolve the issues. I'm sure there is some template black magic that needs to be done here, but I'm at a loss as to what it is. Can anyone give me a pointer as to what's going wrong here?

Comment: `endpoint_type` and `socket_base` aren't in the global namespace.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try fully qualifying both types.

Comment: Okay, now it hates that I don't give it an argument list. What argument list does it want? Some template madness, surely.

Comment: For which class? You should use types from `boost::asio::ip::tcp` or `boost::asio::ip::udp` as they have typedef'd the basic types with their correct template arguments.

Comment: I'm using UDP, so I guess I need to look there...